# Django: Prevent users from editing other accounts

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a simple API for editing user profile.

```
class EditProfile(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

How can I prevent the user from editing other user's profile?

Comment: do not do `objects.all()` but rather do `objects.get()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply define `get_object` so that it always returns the current user.

```
def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user
```

Note there's now no need to specify a slug parameter in the URL.